# sass interpolation with variable names

Tags: css, sass, refactoring

I have a code like this. Is there any way to refactor it with a loop over a list or something like this?

```
.box-heading_orange
    background-color: g.$orange

.box-heading_teal
    background-color: g.$teal

.box-heading_dark-teal
    background-color: g.$dark-teal

.box-heading_light-blue
    background-color: g.$light-blue

.box-heading_dark-blue
    background-color: g.$dark-blue

.box-heading_dark-gray
    background-color: g.$darker-gray
```

Interpolation seems to be fitting here perfectly, but I can't interpolate sass-variable name. Or can I?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to reference a variable dynamically with sass. In your case, you can simply use a [map](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps) and [`@each`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each) loop:

```
$colors: (orange: g.$orange, teal: g.$teal, dark-teal: g.$dark-teal, ...)

@each $colorName, $color in $colors
    .box-heading_#{$colorName}
        background-color: $color
```